# Definition of each column of a View

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, view, metadata

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTIONS(
SHOP_CODE VARCHAR2(10),
BILL_NO NUMBER(10),
TRAN_DATE DATE,
BILL_DATE DATE,
BILL_AMOUNT NUMBER(10,2)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST55 AS 
SELECT SHOP_CODE,BILL_NO V_NO,TRAN_DATE, TO_CHAR(BILL_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') BILL_DATE, NVL(BILL_AMOUNT,0) BILL_AMOUNT,
       (SELECT 'X' FROM DUAL) U_NAME              
  FROM TRANSACTIONS;
/


**Expected result** 
COLUMN_ID       COLUMN_NAME     COLUMN_EXPRESSION
------------    -------------   ----------------------------------
1               SHOP_CODE       SHOP_CODE
2               V_NO            BILL_NO
3               TRAN_DATE       TRAN_DATE
4               BILL_DATE       TO_CHAR(BILL_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY')
5               BILL_AMOUNT     NVL(BILL_AMOUNT,0)
6               U_NAME          (SELECT 'X' FROM DUAL)
```

I need to get the expected result as mentioned above.
How can I achieve this?
I have tried using DBMS_METADATA, DBMS_SQL but the expected result was not generated.

Comment: I don't think Oracle stores the defining expresion information on a per-column basis.  You can get the entire view definition using `user_views`, though.  You can get the types in `user_tab_columns`.

Comment: Not possible. The best bet would have been `SELECT column_id,  column_name, data_default AS COLUMN_EXPRESSION FROM  all_tab_columns WHERE table_name='TEST55'`, but that doesn't work for a view, only for a virtual column of a table

Comment: You will have to parse the view source to get the *column expression*. In generall this presentation is not possible as not all views are as simple as your example. Consider more complex views which  selects from a subquery as an example.

Comment: This is a task for your presentation layer. It is just a simple pivot of the result. Typically quite an easy task for it while the database layer it is almost impossible if not completely. (Not only Oracle RDBMS but any RDBMS.)